# Representing legend in matrix form in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, legend

I am supposed to represent the legend as a 2X3 matrix including the line style in the matrix (like dashed represent one curve, straight line represents other curve).

I did lot of google search but did not really get anything. Legend flex also didn't work.

Can you kindly suggest how can I align my legend data manually in a matrix form ??

Comment: I don't understand.  What do you mean "in matrix form"? Can you show us a visual example?

Comment: Is this what you want? http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/multi-column-grid-legend

Comment: I do not have any visualization. But I want to arrange this in 2X3 like this 0.0 0.5 0.75
1.0 straight line(Thick) Dashed (Thick) Dotted (Thick)
1.5 straight line(Thin) Dashed (Thin) Dotted (Thin)
These thick and thin lines are the lines from the graph. Is to possible to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I realized there are no such formats supported on Matlab legend formats. Therefore, I ended up editing the text box with extra spaces and symbols. However, I still believe there is a way to insert a matrix on the plots like legends.